# Compiling c++ with Armadillo library at NeatBeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, armadillo

I am going to compile C++ program which contains Armadillo library.
This issue is feasible via command line with this command:

```
g++ '/arm.cpp' -o example -O1 -larmadillo
```

But when I add -O1 -larmadillo to the compile options of my NetBeans project I get a considerable amount of errors.

I got these errors:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/atx/NetBeansProjects/armadillo'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/armadillo
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/atx/NetBeansProjects/armadillo'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++ -O3    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/armadillo build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o  
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `gemv<double>':
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:79: undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemv_'
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:79: undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemv_'
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:79: undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemv_'
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:79: undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemv_'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `gemm<double>':
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:114: undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemm_'
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:114: undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemm_'
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:114: undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemm_'
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:114: undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemm_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/armadillo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/atx/NetBeansProjects/armadillo'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/atx/NetBeansProjects/armadillo'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 136ms)
```

Comment: it would help if you show us the errors so we can better help you

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your Armadillo installation is incomplete, or you have two versions of Armadillo installed. I recommend that you manually uninstall any previous versions of Armadillo (both the includes and the run-time library) and then do a fresh install, using a freshly downloaded Armadillo .tar.gz package: http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html

Alternatively, you can work around the issue you're having.  Edit "include/armadillo_bits/config.hpp" and comment out the line with ARMA_USE_WRAPPER. Then, instead of linking with -larmadillo, link with -lblas -llapack

Comment: Have the linking errors changed? If you're still getting linking errors, the most probable explanation is that you have 2 copies of Armadillo, and the compiler is using the unedited or old version.

I recommend to explicitly tell the compiler where your installation of Armadillo is located (this could be simply where you unpacked a fresh Armadillo archive).  For example, if Armadillo is in /home/blah/armadillo-3.2.2,  you can specify the include folder like this:

g++ myprog.cpp -o myprog -O2 -I /home/blah/armadillo-3.2.2/include -llapack -lblas

Comment: It's not helpful to just say "it works" or "it does not work", why not share with us what you have done to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

I know this was an old question, but I had troubles recently with this so I want to help if someone else encounters same problems as I did. This is how-to setup Armadillo library in NetBeans C++ on 64 bit Windows 7.

1. Download the latest version of Armadillo from http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html
2. Unpack it in some directory, where ever you want.
3. Go to Netbeans -> Project Properties -> C++ Compiler

   3.1 Include Directories -> find your Armadillo directory and select folder "include".

   3.2 Preprocessor Definitions -> ARMA_USE_LAPACK ARMA_USE_BLAS
4. Go to Netbeans -> Project Properties -> Linker

   4.1 Additional Library Directories -> find your Armadillo directory and select folder "examples/lib_win64".

   4.2 Additional Dependencies -> lapack_win64_MT.lib blas_win64_MT.lib
5. Go to your project's folder and add files from Armadillo/examples/lib_win64. 4 files should be added -> blas_win64_MT.dll, blas_win64_MT.lib, lapack_win64_MT.dll and lapack_win64_MT.lib.

This should be it. Now you can use Armadillo library in C++, just add in your cpp #include  and if you want using namespace arma;

I hope this was helpful! Cheers!