# Armadillo library used in a c++ program on Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, armadillo

I am trying to use the Armadillo library in a c++ program I am compiling with Cygwin version of g++ through Netbeans.  Armadillo's instructions are a little confusing on this topic and they don't have anything specific to my exact setup that I am trying to use.  I did find this [Compiling c++ with Armadillo library at NeatBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889629/compiling-c-with-armadillo-library-at-neatbeans) on stackoverflow and followed BMaster23's suggestions to a T and originally got the following errors:

```
cd 'C:\Users\Ben\Google Drive\School\BMI 8020\Assignements\Program Assignment 
2\BMI8020_Assignment_2'
C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-
conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Ben/Google Drive/School/BMI 
8020/Assignements/Program Assignment 2/BMI8020_Assignment_2'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin-
Windows/bmi8020_assignment_2.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Ben/Google Drive/School/BMI 
8020/Assignements/Program Assignment 2/BMI8020_Assignment_2'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'lapack_win64_MT.lib', needed by 
'dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/bmi8020_assignment_2.exe'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Ben/Google Drive/School/BMI 
8020/Assignements/Program Assignment 2/BMI8020_Assignment_2'
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: .build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Ben/Google Drive/School/BMI 
8020/Assignements/Program Assignment 2/BMI8020_Assignment_2'
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:40: .build-impl] Error 2
```

I have tried several different things like downloading some different dll and lib files from here http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/ and using them and substituting them in the Additional Dependencies and get the same error as above.

Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: As requested the code I am trying to run is just Armadillo's example code.  I would think it would be valid code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

// Armadillo documentation is available at:
// http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
  {
  cout << "Armadillo version: " << arma_version::as_string() << endl;

  mat A(2,3);  // directly specify the matrix size (elements are uninitialised)

  cout << "A.n_rows: " << A.n_rows << endl;  // .n_rows and .n_cols are read only
  cout << "A.n_cols: " << A.n_cols << endl;

  A(1,2) = 456.0;  // directly access an element (indexing starts at 0)
  A.print("A:");

  A = 5.0;         // scalars are treated as a 1x1 matrix
  A.print("A:");

  A.set_size(4,5); // change the size (data is not preserved)

  A.fill(5.0);     // set all elements to a particular value
  A.print("A:");

  // endr indicates "end of row"
  A << 0.165300 << 0.454037 << 0.995795 << 0.124098 << 0.047084 << endr
    << 0.688782 << 0.036549 << 0.552848 << 0.937664 << 0.866401 << endr
    << 0.348740 << 0.479388 << 0.506228 << 0.145673 << 0.491547 << endr
    << 0.148678 << 0.682258 << 0.571154 << 0.874724 << 0.444632 << endr
    << 0.245726 << 0.595218 << 0.409327 << 0.367827 << 0.385736 << endr;

  A.print("A:");

  // determinant
  cout << "det(A): " << det(A) << endl;

  // inverse
  cout << "inv(A): " << endl << inv(A) << endl;

  // save matrix as a text file
  A.save("A.txt", raw_ascii);

  // load from file
  mat B;
  B.load("A.txt");

  // submatrices
  cout << "B( span(0,2), span(3,4) ):" << endl << B( span(0,2), span(3,4) ) << endl;

  cout << "B( 0,3, size(3,2) ):" << endl << B( 0,3, size(3,2) ) << endl;

  cout << "B.row(0): " << endl << B.row(0) << endl;

  cout << "B.col(1): " << endl << B.col(1) << endl;

  // transpose
  cout << "B.t(): " << endl << B.t() << endl;

  // maximum from each column (traverse along rows)
  cout << "max(B): " << endl << max(B) << endl;

  // maximum from each row (traverse along columns)
  cout << "max(B,1): " << endl << max(B,1) << endl;

  // maximum value in B
  cout << "max(max(B)) = " << max(max(B)) << endl;

  // sum of each column (traverse along rows)
  cout << "sum(B): " << endl << sum(B) << endl;

  // sum of each row (traverse along columns)
  cout << "sum(B,1) =" << endl << sum(B,1) << endl;

  // sum of all elements
  cout << "accu(B): " << accu(B) << endl;

  // trace = sum along diagonal
  cout << "trace(B): " << trace(B) << endl;

  // generate the identity matrix
  mat C = eye<mat>(4,4);

  // random matrix with values uniformly distributed in the [0,1] interval
  mat D = randu<mat>(4,4);
  D.print("D:");

  // row vectors are treated like a matrix with one row
  rowvec r;
  r << 0.59119 << 0.77321 << 0.60275 << 0.35887 << 0.51683;
  r.print("r:");

  // column vectors are treated like a matrix with one column
  vec q;
  q << 0.14333 << 0.59478 << 0.14481 << 0.58558 << 0.60809;
  q.print("q:");

  // convert matrix to vector; data in matrices is stored column-by-column
  vec v = vectorise(A);
  v.print("v:");

  // dot or inner product
  cout << "as_scalar(r*q): " << as_scalar(r*q) << endl;

  // outer product
  cout << "q*r: " << endl << q*r << endl;

  // multiply-and-accumulate operation (no temporary matrices are created)
  cout << "accu(A % B) = " << accu(A % B) << endl;

  // example of a compound operation
  B += 2.0 * A.t();
  B.print("B:");

  // imat specifies an integer matrix
  imat AA;
  imat BB;

  AA << 1 << 2 << 3 << endr << 4 << 5 << 6 << endr << 7 << 8 << 9;
  BB << 3 << 2 << 1 << endr << 6 << 5 << 4 << endr << 9 << 8 << 7;

  // comparison of matrices (element-wise); output of a relational operator is a umat
  umat ZZ = (AA >= BB);
  ZZ.print("ZZ:");

  // cubes ("3D matrices")
  cube Q( B.n_rows, B.n_cols, 2 );

  Q.slice(0) = B;
  Q.slice(1) = 2.0 * B;

  Q.print("Q:");

  // 2D field of matrices; 3D fields are also supported
  field<mat> F(4,3); 

  for(uword col=0; col < F.n_cols; ++col)
  for(uword row=0; row < F.n_rows; ++row)
    {
    F(row,col) = randu<mat>(2,3);  // each element in field<mat> is a matrix
    }

  F.print("F:");

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Question is quite vague, post some code so we know what you did and get able to help you